# Compression algorithm operating on pre-built dictionary as data structure

Tags: java, dictionary, data-structures, compression

I was fairly sure this is a common use case, but after half day of googling I have to fill a question.

I would really like an algorithm, that I can run on a corpus of data to determine dictionary (as a data structure), and then use that dictionary to compress newly arriving data very fast and efficient thanks to that dictionary.

For example, I would run it on 10,000 messages totalling 10MB to determine a dictionary data structure, share this dictionary between all parties and then exchange messages while enjoying very fast and strong compression.

Is there something of that sort? IBM DB2 [does exactly that](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0052331.html) but I doubt they open-sourced the approach. zlib [allows one to pass dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19965559/reusing-a-data-dictionary-for-deflate-separate-from-the-compressed-data), but it is raw byte array which will need to be processed for every message, and there's no method of generating said byte array.

The idea of holding a data structure in memory is to avoid any overhead of per-message processing.

Bonus points for Java implementations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eventually I was pointed to [Zstd compression](https://github.com/facebook/zstd) that allow supplying your own (shared) dictionary. There are [Java bindings](https://github.com/luben/zstd-jni) with capability of dictionary training based on samples.

It is able to outperform my own algorithm with shared dictionary as small as 512 bytes:

[image: compression efficiencies]
(`s` is number of samples, `d` is dictionary length, `l` is compression level)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up implementing my own compression using LZW-Huffman hybrid.

I build a dictionary (using reference data set) using LZW where codepoints map to byte sequences, and then make Huffman tree from those codepoints' frequencies. Then I use TreeMap to find byte sequences in input array, pass them to Huffman coder.

It works reasonably well. 0.4 compression is typical on ~120 byte entries, where GZip gives 0.75.

Still I'm interested in optimized stock solutions for this problem.